# A diophantine equation inspired in a conjecture due to Gica and Luca

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, diophantine-equations, mersenne-numbers

In this post I consider the equation $$k\cdot x=y^2+z^2(x^2-2)-2\tag{1}$$
over odd integers $y\geq 1$ and $z\geq 1$, and over integers $k\geq 1$ and Mersenne exponents $x\geq 13$ such that $x^2-2$ is a prime number.

Previous diophatine equation $(1)$ is consequence of Fermat's little theorem applied to the diophantine equation studied by professors Alexandru Gica and Florian Luca in Conjecture 4 of [1]. Mersene exponents is the sequence [*A000043*](https://oeis.org/search?q=A000043) from The On-Line Encyclopedia of Integer Sequences (I add that also Wikipedia has the article [*Mersenne prime*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mersenne_prime)).

I wondered about this problem that I've stated after I've realized that the $x's$ of the solutions $(x,y,z)$ of professors in [1], **in the context of their Conjecture 4**, are Mersenne exponents.

> **Question (Edited).** I would like to know a Mersenne exponent $x>31$ with $x^2-2$ also a prime number, for which we are able to find or characterize all solutions of the corresponding equation $(1)$, over $k\geq 1$ integer, and over odd integers $y\geq 1$ and $z\geq 1$. **Many thanks.**

**Example.** I've calculated the first two solutions for $x=61$,

$$61k=y^2+3719z^2-2,$$ that are
$(k;y,z)=(118;59,1)$ and $(126;63,1)$ I wondered for this $x$ or a different Mersenne exponent $x>31$ we can find all solutions (I'm interested in a case in which the set of solutions is not empty, as for $x=61$).

### References:

[1] Alexandru Gica and Florian Luca, *On the Diophantine equation* $2^x=x^2+y^2-2$, Funct. Approx. Comment. Math. 46(1): 109-116 (March 2012).

Comment: I can get the paper as free access.

Comment: What precisely is a 'Mersenne exponent'? A positive integer $x$ for which $2^x-1$ is prime?

Comment: Yes @Mastrem I'm going to edit adding the Wikipedia *Mersenne primes*

Comment: Then the set of all known Mersenne exponents only has $51$ elements, the largest of which is $82589933$, which isn't too big. You can therefore begin by finding the finite set of all known such $x$ for which $x^2-2$ prime.

Comment: You're right in part +1 for your comment, but for those $x$ with $x^2-2$ we must to rule out or to study the corresponding/resulting diophantine equation for such $x$. My computer it broke few weeks ago, thus I tried to check more exponents $x$ as soon I'm connected to internet. On the other hand my question is (also) about if some person has some idea, since the Mersenne exponents are enconded in Lucas-Lehmer test and there is literature about these. Many thanks, next week I try to edit the post.

Comment: @user759001 Why do you need a computer to check whether $x^2-2$ is prime for these few numbers?

Comment: I've calculated some of those Mersenne exponents such that $x^2-2$ is composite with a symbolic calculator, but I've considered update the question to focus about the solution set of a specific diophantine equation. Many thanks to you @Thissitehasbecomeadump. and previous user in comments. My problem is that without a computer (my computer is broken) it is difficult to provide computational evidence

Comment: @user759001: Care to provide your particular motivation for considering $x = 61$ first?  You may shoot me an e-mail.

Comment: There isn't not any special about it, this is just an example for a small integer in comparison to my question edited on MathOverflow with identifier **425571** that is for a large integer (and I'm discouraged, especially communicating with people, since my father  passed away a few weeks ago) @JOSEARNALDOBEBITADRIS

Comment: @user759001:  My sincerest condolences.

Comment: Many thanks @JOSEARNALDOBEBITADRIS